# Search in struct array

Tags: database, go

I have a struct defined like this :

```
type Issues struct {
    RedmineIssue string
    GitlabIssue string
}
```

Then I get the list from the DB

```
    database.Find(&Issues)
```

Then I have another array

```
   redmineIssues []redmine.Issue
```

Is there any way to search issues in my array Issues  that are also in the array redmineIssues base on field RedmineIssue ( string ) ?

---

Today here is what I'm doing

```
    database.Find(&Issues)
    redmineIssue := []string{}
    for _, issueRedmine := range Issues {
        redmineIssue = append(redmineIssue, issueRedmine.RedmineIssue)
    }

    gitlabissues := []string{}
    for _, issueGitlab := range Issues {
        gitlabissues = append(gitlabissues, issueGitlab.GitlabIssue)
    }
```

Then I can compare with another array I have

```
for _, issueR := range IssueFromRedmineWS {
    inArray, _ := in_array(issueR.Id, redmineIssue)
    if !inArray {
        // The issue is not in the DB
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to optimize this and to make it cleaner?

Comment: How does `readmineIssues` relate to `readmineIssue`?

Comment: It's not possible to range over a struct type identifier. ie. If `type Issues struct{...` then `range Issues` will not compile. Neither will `database.Find(&Issues)`.

Comment: I'd recommend you consider offloading filtering to the db. That ought to be much more efficient, assuming you have the proper indexes in place, then loading all of the issue records into your app and doing the filtering there.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is the right way to go. Assuming the code you pasted *actually works*, you can merge those into a single for loop, the way you have it written.

```
database.Find(&Issues)
redmineIssue := []string{}
gitlabissues := []string{}
for _, issue := range Issues {
    redmineIssue = append(redmineIssue, issue.RedmineIssue)
    gitlabissues = append(gitlabissues, issue.GitlabIssue)
}
```

But this assumes that `Issues` is an array. Which doesn't match the rest of your question. According to your stated definition of `Issues`, the code you posted won't even compile, though. So I don't know if this code will work for you, either.

You can provide another micro-optimization by pre-allocating the arrays:

```
database.Find(&Issues)
redmineIssue := make([]string{}, 0, len(Issues))
gitlabissues := make([]string{}, 0, len(Issues))
```

Comment: Indeed , Issues is an array.